# How to style an element created with JavaScript by using the HTML id attribute

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to style an element created with JavaScript like this:

```
  const h1 = document.createElement("h1");
  h1.textContent = data.name;
  h1.setAttribute("id", "heading");
  window.data.appendChild(h1);
```

This is my CSS code:

```
#heading{
  padding-right: 100px;
  colour: red;
}
```

The element appears on the page since i have an async function which takes data from a JSON file, but i don't see a difference in the style of the element. I can't seem to find the issue in the code since I am new to JavaScript too.

Comment: I'm surprised `window.data.appendChild(h1)` works :/

Comment: shouldn't it be `document.appendChild(h1)`?

Comment: `document.appendChild(h1)` doesn't seem to work. I will see if i can create a snippet.

Comment: @Jacob Why are you surprised? Element IDs are automatically turned into `window` properties.

Comment: And window properties are also global variables.

Comment: `colour` should be `color`

Comment: Try `document.body.appendChild(h1)`.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you! After the correction of the `color` property it became obvious that the code in the post was working, it was just not seeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`color` instead of `colour`.
`window.data` is undifined

```
const h1 = document.createElement("h1");
h1.textContent = data.name;
h1.setAttribute("id", "heading");
document.getElementById("content").appendChild(h1);
```

demo :
https://jsfiddle.net/smaha/gx71y63h/3/

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like this should work:

```
h1.style.color = "red";
h1.style.paddingRight = "100px";
```

Check documentation for other specific cases
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp

Also, a good practice in CSS is to avoid to target your element with **id**. Use HTML tag directly if possible or **class**

In your case, instead of

```
h1.setAttribute("id", "heading");
```

you should

```
h1.classList.add("heading");
```

Then in your CSS (If needed)

```
.heading{
  padding-right: 100px;
  colour: red;
}
```